# How to send my __arglist parametr to another function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm calling a C Export function which doesn't let me to use params!

Code :

```
    public  static void CallIt1(string Format, __arglist)
    {
        //Processing Data

    }

    public  static void CallIt2(__arglist)
    {
        CallIt1("myform", ?);

    }
```

I need to send all of the parameters which are sent to CallIt2 to another function CallIt1.
C# doesn't let me to declare a variable __arglist.
Any idea how to do `CallIt1("myform", Call2ARGS);` ?

Comment: Use `params object[] args` instead of `__arglist`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I'm calling a C export function and can't go with params

Comment: Is this literal code? Post the _exact_ import statement and maybe the exact `C` as well. As I read it now, it should simply be `int __arglist`.

Comment: @Mahdi And how was anyone supposed to know you're calling a C export function? Please add ALL relevant details in your question.

Comment: http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx

Comment: @BartoszKP Sorry but I taught my question it's clear since I didn't ask for alternative ways but only __arglist. However I have edited my question

Comment: @Mahdi All right. There is a good rule of thumb regarding it - don't stop clarifying when you think it's clear enough. Stop clarifying when something can't be stated clearer - this way you will be understood more often, more likely :)

Comment: @Mahdi the `__arglist` keyword isn't really intended for general use, it was specifically included in the standard to support C++/CLI, not saying you can't or shouldn't use it. I just recommend you use it very very carefully as it breaks CLI compliance, making it so that your interface can only be called from a subset of CLI languages.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call inside c# (not clear to me) can try:

```
public static void CallIt1(string Format, ArgIterator iterator)
{
    //Processing Data
}

public static void CallIt2(__arglist)
{
    CallIt1("myform", new ArgIterator(__arglist));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to convert ArgIterator back to __arglist ?

Answer (score 0):

as  you  are doing marshaling between unmanaged and managed environment  you should declare your function in C# like this:

```
[DllImport(my_C_dll, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void print_string_array([In] string[] str_array, IntPtr length);
```

As it is written, your C code would appear to use the cdecl calling convention. So you may need to make the C# declaration match. I suspect that is the main problem you are facing.
please try  to take a look at this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) first

Comment: @Mgetz I think  it would be better that the OP  post  a bit more of details if it's possible

Comment: Thanks but that is not my problem, I just want to send __arglist from one funcion to another inside C# which has nothing to do with C++ part in this question.

Comment: yes even if you are using the c# to let the C/C++ funcions communicates between them you  still  need marshalling